# Error making http request across linked Docker containers

Tags: angularjs, http, elasticsearch, docker

I'm building a web application with Angular.js 2, Elasticsearch, and Docker.

I'm trying to access Elasticsearch via its REST API from my Angular app using the linked url "http://search:9200/_cat/health", but I'm getting a `GET http://search:9200/_cat/health net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

The weird thing is that when I do `curl -XGET "http://search:9200/_cat/health"` from inside the web app's container everything is fine and I'm getting a correct response.

Here is my respective `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2'
services:
  search:
    image: elasticsearch:latest
    command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - .:/visfx
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - search
```

also here's the call to the elasticsearch service

```
@Injectable()
export class ElasticsearchService {
    private _esUrl = 'http://search:9200';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getHealthString() {
        let healthUrl = '/_cat/health';

        return this.http.get(this._esUrl + healthUrl)
            .map(res => <string>res.text())
            .do(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If that javascript is running on the client side you'll have to use a real DNS name which routes to the docker host as docker's names are only resolved using docker's internal resolver.

Comment: Also docker compose will create you a private network automatically so you don't need to specify any links explicitly in the config.

Comment: various thoughts ... i assume docker has made an /etc/hosts entry for the search container inside your web container ... can you ping the search container? is the elastic container whitelisting IPs that can access it? is there any firewalls involved?

Comment: It was as @tpbowden said, my code was running in the front end. I configured elasticsearch cors setting to allow docker's 192.168.99.100 ip

Comment: @tpbowden can you post your comment as an answer; then this question can be marked as answered by George Ludakis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that javascript is running on the client side you'll have to use a real DNS name which routes to the docker host as docker's names are only resolved using docker's internal resolver.

Comment: Hi, I'm having that same problem. How I configure that? May I ask for an example?